# Passing data from partial view to parent view

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, user-interface

I am trying to pass a value from partial view to parent view. I tried the below which didn't worked for me. Can some one help me out how can I achieve this? By using the value that partial view returned, I am trying to hide a button which is in the parent view.

Parent View:

```
    <div id="ProductCount">
    @{
        Html.RenderAction("ProductPartialView", "ProductList", new { area = "PR", ProductID = Model.ProductID, allowSelect = true});
    }

<div class="saveBtnArea">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit App" id="btn-submit" />
</div>

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var ProductCount = jQuery("#ProductCount").val();

            if (ProductCount == 0) {
                jQuery("#btn-submit").hide();
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#btn-submit").show();
            }
        });
```

Partial View:

```
<fieldset>
<div>
<input type="hidden" id="ProductCount" value="5" />
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What is it that is supposed to be returned? And what do you want to do.

Comment: Also you have 2 elements with id of `ProductCount`: `div` and `input`. Thus when you select `jQuery("#ProductCount")` it will select both. This is probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement change event for hidden input field like this

```
$('#ProductCount').change(function(){
      var ProductCount = $(this).val();

      if (ProductCount == 0) {
            jQuery("#btn-submit").hide();
      }
      else {
            jQuery("#btn-submit").show();
      }
}).trigger('change');

$('#ProductCount').val(5);
```

```js
$('#ProductCount').change(function(){
      var ProductCount = $(this).val();
      
      if (ProductCount == 0) {
            jQuery("#btn-submit").hide();
      }
      else {
            jQuery("#btn-submit").show();
      }
}).trigger('change');

$('#ProductCount').val(5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='hidden' id='ProductCount' />

<button id='btn-submit'>Submit</button>
```